# Publish to a friend wall on facebook, using koala, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-oauth, facebook-wall, koala

I'm trying to publish to a person wall (friend of the user), on behalf of an user using the koala gem.

I configured the publish_stream permission, and I can publish to the user wall, but when I try to publish to a friend wall, like this

`@graph.put_wall_post("testing this posting on wall!", {:name => "..."}, "id")`

I get an error

`OAuthException, code: 200, message: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action [HTTP 403]`

What am i missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What permissions are you requesting in the login code? Is `publish_stream` one of them? Are you aware that the functionality you're using is scheduled for removal in two weeks?

Comment: Yes, publish_stream is one of them. I wasn't aware of that. What will be the way then?

Comment: Look at the Feb changes in https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ - the ability to post to a friend's profile without using the dialog will be removed, you can still post to the current user's profile, tag friends in Open Graph actions, or use the dialog to post

Comment: Please show your permissions.

Comment: This functionality was removed from facebook API @majioa. JS API is now used to do that.

Comment: @Ron strangely, did you see koala's :put_connections method?